# Clock Component do not update due to Warning: Text content did not match

Tags: reactjs

The clock component I have will display time (such as Thursday 10th June 2021 10:45:11 am), with time updating every second. There is an error after re-compiling the website.

Error Message:

```
react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "10:45:07 am" Client: "10:45:10 am"
    at p
    at div
    at Clock
```

Clock Component:

```
const Clock = () => {

      const [day, setDay] = useState<String>(moment().format('dddd'))
      const [date, setDate] = useState<String>(moment().format('Do MMMM YYYY'))
      const [clock, setClock] = useState<String>(moment().format('h:mm:ss a'))
      useEffect(() => {
            //change display time every second
            const timer = setInterval(() => {
                  setDay(moment().format('dddd'))
                  setDate(moment().format('Do MMMM YYYY'))
                  setClock(moment().format('h:mm:ss a'))
            }, 1000)

            return () => {
                  clearInterval(timer)
            }
      })

      return (
            <div className="mx-4 my-2 justify-self-end">
                  <p className="text-4xl font-semibold text-gray-800">{day} {date}</p>
                  <p className="text-lg text-gray-400 font-semibold float-right mr-1">{clock}</p>
            </div>
      )
}

export default Clock;
```

index.tsx

```
 <div className="grid">
     <Clock />
 </div>
```

update:
I've changed to use requestAnimationFrame, however, the same error still appears.

```
const Clock = () => {
      const requestRef = useRef(0)
      const previousTimeRef = useRef(new Date())
      const [day, setDay] = useState<String>(moment().format('dddd'))
      const [date, setDate] = useState<String>(moment().format('Do MMMM YYYY'))
      const [time, setTime] = useState<String>(moment().format('h:mm:ss a'))

      const tick = () => {
            previousTimeRef.current = new Date()
            requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(tick)
            setDay(moment().format('dddd'))
            setDate(moment().format('Do MMMM YYYY'))
            setTime(moment().format('h:mm:ss a'))
      }
      useEffect(() => {
            requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(tick)
            return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current)
      }, [])

      return (
            <div className="mx-4 my-2 justify-self-end">
                  <p className="text-4xl font-semibold text-gray-800">{day} {date}</p>
                  <p className="text-lg text-gray-400 font-semibold float-right mr-1">{time}</p>
            </div>
      )
}

export default Clock;
```

Comment: I've updated the code as in the updated section in the questions. The same error still appear after using requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: The error disappeared if I use suppressHydrationWarning in the <p>